# How to remove need for hacks to run scrot with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nixos, awesome, scrot

I'd like to take screenshots with a keyboard shortcut using `scrot --select`. I tried adding the following to [my rc.lua](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/blob/4d406414ac688e2232ba9e894789e554f918dd7e/.config/awesome/rc.lua) to use the <kbd>PrintScr</kbd> key for this purpose:

```
awful.key({}, "Print", function () awful.spawn("scrot --select") end,
    {description = "take screenshot of selection", group = "client"}),
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error message in the xsession systemd journal:

> giblib error: couldn't grab keyboard:Resource temporarily unavailable

It seems `scrot` needs to grab the keyboard while I'm still holding down the <kbd>Fn+PrintScr</kbd> combination. [One way to work around this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35503871/96588) complicates the function a fair bit:

```
awful.spawn.with_shell("sleep 0.5 && scrot --select")
```

The `.with_shell` and `sleep` bits are a hack to give me time to release the keys before `scrot` runs. Which of course means that if I hold down the keys for too long the command still fails with the same error as above.

[A more elegant workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51789019/96588) does not work reliably. I installed xdotool, set `xdotool key XF86Ungrab && scrot --select` as the screenshot command, and added `grab:break_actions` to `services.xserver.xkbOptions`, but I still get the same error as above *most of the time.* Pressing <kbd>Fn+PrintScr</kbd> repeatedly will eventually work, for no discernible reason.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to your problem but it works if using `maim` instead of `scrot`. In addition I'm using `xclip` to automatically copy the image into my clipboard which is very handy.

```lua
awful.key({}, "#107",
  function ()
    awful.util.spawn_with_shell("FILE=" .. os.getenv("HOME") .. "/Media/Screenshots/snapshot-$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S).png && maim -s --hidecursor $FILE && xclip -selection clipboard $FILE -t image/png")
  end),
```