# Setting a keyboard shortcut to interactively select a screenshot (sxhkd/scrot)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot, sxhkd, scrot

I would like to add a keyboard shortcut using [sxhkd](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) let me select a region of my desktop to screenshot using [scrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot). This should be accomplished by adding this section to my sxhkd file,

```
ctrl + alt + x
    scrot --select
```

but this doesn't work. The command `scrot --select` works fine when issued from a terminal, and this keyboard shortcut works fine if I change `--select` to something non-interactive like `--focused`, so I'm not sure why the above sxhkd entry is not working, but I suspect that it has to do with `--select` being interactive. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/538021/74616) the command `scrot --select` also grabs control of your keyboard (and will cancel the screenshot if a key is pressed). So you need to tell sxhkd to run the scrot command *after the keys are released*. This can be done by adding an `@`.

```
ctrl + alt + @x
    scrot --select
```